# c# Nunit .Is.EquivalentTo not behaving as expected for a List<T>

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-4.5

I am using NUnit in .net 4.5.2 project

Using the Collection assertions thusly:

Assert.That(first, Is.EquivalentTo(second));

This unit test passed

```
        [Test] 
        public void Test_Int_ExampleDeepListCompare()
        {


            List<List<string>> first = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                new List<string> { "1", "3" },
                new List<string> { "1", "2" },
                new List<string> { "a", "b" }
            };

            List<List<string>> second = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                new List<string> { "1", "2" },
                new List<string> { "1", "3" },
                new List<string> { "a", "b" }
            };


            
            Assert.That(first, Is.EquivalentTo(second));
        }
```

So then I used it on one of our classes that look equivalent in the debugger and it failed.

To test that, I created a simple reproduction, which still fails, now I'm really confused

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_Int_ExampleDeepCompareCustomObjects2()
    {
        List<SimpleObject> rtnValFakeA = new List<SimpleObject>() { new SimpleObject() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Jones", Mi = "a", StudId = 12345 } };
        List<SimpleObject> rtnValFakeb = new List<SimpleObject>() { new SimpleObject() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Jones", Mi = "a", StudId = 12345 } };

        //assert with deep compare ignoring order - EWB
        Assert.That(rtnValFakeA, Is.EquivalentTo(rtnValFakeb));
    }
```

The object definition, used in example two, I figure has to be something here:

```
public class SimpleObject
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Mi { get; set; }

    public Int64 StudId { get; set; }

}
```

The second test fails with the message:

Expected: equivalent to < <_Test_DAL.SimpleObject> >
But was:  < <_Test_DAL.SimpleObject> >

at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
at _Test_DAL.TestADStudentDAL.Test_Int_ExampleDeepCompareCustomObjects2() in d:\TFS\JCDCHelper\2013\JCDCHelper.DAL_Tests\DAL\TestADStudentDAL.cs:line 152

But I totally expected it to pass

Why does the first pass, and the second fail? They look equivalent to me.

How do I create a test to deep compare those two objects, order-independent in .Net 4.5.2, as that is a standard object implementation for us

I want to write tests like the one above.
We are moving from Sybase ASE to SqlServer, and I want to assert that the Ase call and the SqlServer call are returning the same data, and I can't just add order to every sql call.

P.S> For political reasons I can't update from .net 4.5.2 to .net 8.* at this time

Comment: Your `SimpleObject` does not override `Equals`, thus every instance will differ from other ones regardless of the property values. If you change it to a `struct` or [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record), then it will likely pass the tests. I'm not suggesting it should be a `struct` (especially if the actual object is even larger); either an overridden `Equals` or turning it to a `record` would be the correct way to go.

Comment: I fixed it using FluentAssertions. I had to search back and install the tip of v4 from the nuget page, to get .Net 4.5.2 support, but after that it was as easy as FirstList<T>.ShouldBeEquivalnetTo( SecondList<T>, "message");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FluentAssertions was by far the easiest answer.

It has a

```
list<T>.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(List <T>)
```

assertion, that performs a deep compare, ignoring order, and on failure returns an error with exactly the fields and values that did not match.

FluentAssertions  v4.19.4 supports .Net 4.5.2

Package Manager Console:
NuGet\Install-Package FluentAssertions -Version 4.19.4

Then wrote my Nunit test.

```
        [Test]
        public void Test_Int_GetSimpleObject_CrossDbDeep()
        {
            List<SimpleObject> rtnValSyb = dal.GetSimpleObject(bForceSybase);
            List<SimpleObject> rtnValMs = dal.GetSimpleObject(bForceMsSql);

            Assert.AreNotEqual(rtnValSyb.Count, 0);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(rtnValMs.Count, 0);

            //assert with deep compare ignoring order - EWB
            rtnValSyb.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(rtnValMs,"If this fails, the data is probably out of synch");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/CollectionEquivalentConstraint.html):

> CollectionEquivalentConstraint tests that two IEnumerables are equivalent - that they **contain the same items**, in any order.

Since `SimpleObject` is reference type default equality is determined by reference, you can override equality members so it will make test pass. For example:

```
public class SimpleObject : IEquatable<SimpleObject>
{
    // ...

    public bool Equals(SimpleObject other)
    {
        return LastName == other.LastName && FirstName == other.FirstName && Mi == other.Mi && StudId == other.StudId;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((SimpleObject)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(LastName, FirstName, Mi, StudId);
    }
}
```

Note that other libraries like `FluentAssertions` support [object graph comparison](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/) without such overrides (something like `rtnValFakeA.Should().BeEquivalentTo(rtnValFakeB)`).